# How do I get status messages of friends through an app of certain date, month etc.?

Tags: facebook, date, facebook-graph-api, status

How do I get status messages of friends through an app of certain date, month etc.? Please provide a link to the appropriate tutorial or documentation page. I have searched a lot but could not get much help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Check by "updated_time" field.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the link. But how do I get the status messages of a particular person? I mean what is the syntax?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT status_id,message,time from status where uid=<user id here> and time = <condition here>

seems to be the answer